# UIActionSheet separators have very unexpected behavior

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactionsheet

I'm creating a standard `UIActionSheet` in which I want no destructive button and the cancel button all the way at the bottom. My other button titles are stored in an `NSArray`.

However, I get really strange behavior of the line separators, especially when I try to add a title.

I'm at a total loss here. Help?

**Implementation #1 (no title)**

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
for (NSString *title in self.myArray) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
}
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar*)self.toolbarView];
```

**Implementation #2 (with title)**

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
for (NSString *title in self.myArray) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
}
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar*)self.toolbarView];
```

**Results #1 (no title)**

When I have 10 or fewer buttons, not including the cancel button, then all the buttons fit on the screen. The line separators extend the full width of the action sheet. This is expected behavior.

When I have 11 or more buttons, the action sheet implements scrolling. The separators now extend all the way left, but leave space (~25px?) on the right. Further, when I scroll up and down, an extra separator (that extends full width) is added/removed to the bottom after the last non-cancel button each time.

1. Open action sheet
2. Scroll to bottom -> No line separator after final button
3. Scroll to top
4. Scroll to bottom -> Line separator that extends full width after final button
5. Scroll to top
6. Scroll to bottom -> No line separator after final button
7. ... etc.

**Results #2 (with title)**

When I have 10 or fewer buttons, not including the cancel button, then all the buttons fit on the screen. The line separators extend the full width of the action sheet. There is also a separator that extends full width between the title at the top, and the first button. This is expected behavior.

When I have 11 or more buttons, the action sheet implements scrolling. The separators now extend all the way left, but leave space (~25px?) on the right. The separator between the title and buttons leaves space on either side of the separator (~5px). Now when I scroll up and down, I get really weird separator behavior with separators getting added and removed in weird places.

1. Open action sheet
2. Scroll to bottom -> Line separator between second-to-last and last button, slightly below the line separator that is already there (~1px?). The new line separator extends full width.
3. Scroll to top -> An extra line separator has been added between the title and the first button. This line separator is the same width (leaves a slight gap on either side), is dark black rather than light gray, and is ~1px below the other separator.
4. Scroll to bottom -> New line separator is still there, but now is black instead of light gray.
5. Further scrolling causes no change

And if I scroll up and down really fast, I can actually get another extra separator between the first and second buttons on my list, black in color, that extends full width.

**Attempted Solution**

I thought maybe I shouldn't use the built-in init function since I'm not really using any parameters. No difference in behavior, with or without the title.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    for (NSString *title in self.myArray) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
}
actionSheet.title = @"Title";
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar*)self.toolbarView];
```

**Attempted Solution #2 (as per Leo Natan)**

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet =[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destroy" otherButtonTitles:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",nil];
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Still no change. If there are enough items on the 'UIActionSheet' to cause it to scroll, the separator behavior becomes erratic.

Comment: Submit your test app demonstrating the problem to Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Can you test two things? What happens if you provide a non-nil `cancelButtonTitle:` during initialization? If you use a `UIAlertController`, does the issue reproduce? Long action sheets are known to be buggy since iOS 7.